# Create conntrack session without a network

Tags: linux, netfilter, ip-conntrack

I'm trying to test some conntrack related tooling. The test runs within a single VM without network access. What's the easiest way to create a conntrack session so I can do my test?

Comment: Why don't you create a second VM and a virtual network between the VMs?

Comment: I'm trying to find a less complicated solution than that